# How to Make This Django's ImageField Work?

Tags: python, django, django-models, rendering, imagefield

**models.py**

`class SpecialOffer(models.Model):
productImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="", null=True, blank=True)
productName = models.CharField('Product Name', max_length=20)

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.productName`
```

**views.py**

`def homepage(request):
specialoffers = SpecialOffer.objects.all()

```
context = {
    'specialoffers' : specialoffers,
}

return render(request, "index.html", context)`
```

**index.html**

`{% for product_name in specialoffers %} <img src="{{ product_name.productImage.url }}" alt="" /> {% endfor %}`

**and the error is that the image i'm uploading through admin sections, is not rendering through my HTML templates. what's wrong with my code?**

I tried changing this `{{ product_name.productImage.url }}` to `{{ product_name.productImage }}` but is still not working.

I also tried setting up the MEDIA_URL, and MEDIA_ROOT.

Comment: You will need to also show us the staticfiles, MEDIA_URL, and MEDIA_ROOT configuration in your settings.py file. So we can properly debug this issue